# DataStore - User is unauthorized to query syncLands with auth mode API_KEY

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, react-native, amazon-dynamodb, aws-amplify

I have an expo app powered by aws amplify that was working fine till a few days ago when I tried to use subscription on a useEffect query. Now even after removing the subscription I get the following error

`DataStore - User is unauthorized to query syncCustomers with auth mode API_KEY. No data could be returned.`

Therefore no data is being fetched from the backend. I searched around the net to find out if there was a known solution but I couldn't find any. According to some it is related to the `Auth mode` but even that didn't work.

Here's a sample of the code

```
import { useWindowDimensions, TouchableOpacity } from "react-native";
import React, { useEffect,  useState } from "react";
import MapView, { PROVIDER_GOOGLE } from "react-native-maps";
import { Amplify, AuthModeStrategyType } from "aws-amplify";
import awsconfig from "../aws-exports";
import { DataStore } from "@aws-amplify/datastore";
import { House, Lands } from "../models";
import LandMark from "../components/LandMark";
import { GestureHandlerRootView } from "react-native-gesture-handler";
import HouseMark from "../components/HouseMark";
import { mapStyle } from "../utils";

Amplify.configure({
  ...awsconfig,
  Analytics: {
    disabled: true,
  },
  DataStore: {
    authModeStrategyType: AuthModeStrategyType.MULTI_AUTH,
  },
});


const SellScreen = () => {
  const [houses, setHouses] = useState();
  const [terrain, setTerrain] = useState();
  const { width, height } = useWindowDimensions();

  useEffect(() => {
   
    try {
      DataStore.query(Lands, (l) => l.available.eq(true)).then(setTerrain);

      DataStore.query(House, (h) => h.available.eq(true)).then(setHouses);

    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }, []);


  return (
    <GestureHandlerRootView className=" flex-1">
      <MapView
        provider={PROVIDER_GOOGLE}
        style={{
          width,
          height,
        }}
        customMapStyle={mapStyle}
        initialRegion={{
          latitude: 1,
          longitude: 2,
          latitudeDelta: 0.7,
          longitudeDelta: 0.7,
        }}
      >

        {terrain &&
          terrain.map((land, id) => (
            <TouchableOpacity key={id}>
              <LandMark land={land} />
            </TouchableOpacity>
          ))}

        {houses &&
          houses.map((house, id) => (
            <TouchableOpacity key={id}>
              <HouseMark house={house} />
            </TouchableOpacity>
          ))}
      </MapView>
    </GestureHandlerRootView>
  );
};

export default SellScreen;
```

I am using Amplify Studio and there's no place where I'm explicitly using GraphQL

Here's the error...

[image]